# Como subir una imagen de la camara dese Ionic a NodeJS

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic

como estan? tengo el siguiente problema, necesito hacer una peticion post Donde envío un formData, para luego recibirlo en un servidor Node.

el problema es el siguiente

yo tengo el siguiente método donde envío la peticion POST

```
  createPost(title:string, description:string, socialLink:string, imgUrl:File){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'authorization': `bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
    })
    const fd =  new FormData();
    fd.append('title', title),
    fd.append('description', description),
    fd.append('socialLink', socialLink),
    //fd.append('category', category)
    fd.append('image', imgUrl)
    return this.http.post(this.URL + 'post',fd,{headers})
  }
```

esto lo hago desde un servicio.

luego, en el page, utilizo la camara para sacar una foto

```
takePicture = async () => {
  const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 90,
    allowEditing: true,
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
  });
  console.log(image)
  };
```

y por último llamo al metodo post para enviar la informacion al servidor

```
 uploadPost(){
    this.post.createPost(this.newPost.title,this.newPost.description,this.newPost.socialLink,this.file)
      .subscribe (
          res => console.log(res),
          err => console.log(err)
      )
  }
```

el problema es que, el método creado en el servicio, para la imagen espera un tipo de dato FILE, pero la camara, al sacar la foto, no me devuelve un tipo de dato FILE, como puedo hacer para enviar esa foto que estoy sacando con la camara en el formdata?

desde ya que les agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Que plugin y version de ionic usas?

Comment: Uso el plugin de capacitor, y la version de Ionic es 6.16.3

Answer (score 0):

Si te llega en Base64 puedes hacer lo siguiente -->

```
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
            
            const base64Response = 
             await  fetch(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`);
             const blob = await base64Response.blob();
             const file = this.blobToFile(blob, 'NameFile');
    
            }, (err) => {
           
            });

public blobToFile(theBlob, fileName){       
    return new File([theBlob], fileName, { lastModified: new Date().getTime(), type: theBlob.type })
}
```

Comment: y con eso, luego como envio el File al servidor?

Comment: tienes tu funcion de post al servidor no? 
 uploadPost(){
    this.post.createPost(this.newPost.title,this.newPost.description,this.newPost.socialLink,this.file (Aqui le pasas el file))
      .subscribe (
          res => console.log(res),
          err => console.log(err)
      )
  }